# adding params to joomla plugin based on external file

Tags: plugins, joomla

I am trying to develope a simple joomla plugin and i have a question, if you kindly could help me.

I have a long list of constants to use in my plugin, a group is to use with a joomla version and another group to use with another version, like this

```
//joomla version 2.5
$a01 = " some value "
$a02 = " some value "
$a03 =" some value "
....
....
$a99 = " some value "

//joomla version 3.0
$b01 = " some value "
$b02 = " some value "
$b03 = " some value "
....
....
$b99 = " some value "
```

In my plugin file i have this code:

```
if (!version_compare(JVERSION, '3.0', 'ge'))            
{
    // do something using constants for version less than 3.0
} else {
    // do something using constants for version more than 3.0
}
```

For a better reading and organization where can hold those constants? In same file or in another file like (params or constants)? Which is the best approach? And how could i implement it?

Comment: Why would you want to create different params for Joomla 2.5 and 3.0. Why not create a custom form field?

Comment: Thank you Lodder. I am trying to change several tag names in both version but those tag names are different in each version.

Answer (score 0):

What about placing it in a db-table? You retrieve them in your plugin by:

```
$db=JFactory::getDbo(); 
$db->setQuery('select key, value from #__yourtable where version ='.$version);
$list=$db-loadAssocList(); 
foreach($list as $v){
  eval("define({$v['key']}, {$v['value']});"); 
}
```

Now all your constants for version $version are loaded.

...and if you want to be able to manage your constants from the joomla backend interface you could use a component-creator to quickly create this simple table with a full editing interface ( try [component-creator.com](http://component-creator.com) )

regards Jonas (not affiliated with component-creator.com :) )